# Accessing the inbox in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android message based application in which i have to access inbox programatically.Can anyone tell how should i pursue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement broadcast rceiver on "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" Action.

After that read message data from intent:

```
Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus"); 

SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length]; 

StringBuilder messageText = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {                 
     messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pduArray [i]);              
     messageText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());          
}
```

Comment: how to implement broadcast receiver

Comment: public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   //do smth
   }
}

In manifest:
<receiver android:name="ReceiverName">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented and supported API in the Android SDK for accessing any sort of "inbox".